# Are there any generalised concenpts of "fair treatment" in UK law?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law

I have a complaint about the way I've been treated by a charitable body. In the fallout from some problems, they have chosen to respond to the financial concerns of a majority customer group, while ignoring a smaller group with the same concerns.

Essentially the situation is this: they were selling tickets for a two-day event, which they have had to change significantly. Those who have one-day tickets are being offered refunds or the option of a free upgrade to a two-day ticket. Those who bought two-day tickets are being ignored.

In terms of contract law, they are watertight: they did not need to respond to any of these concerns. Instead, they've chosen only to look after those in a particular situation. A cynic might conclude this is a purposeful attempt at damage limitation to save money. It is also manifestly unfair - the sums involved run to the hundreds of pounds.

Either way, splitting their customer base like that is manifestly unfair. I am curious to know if there are any further legal principles I could use to take a complaint forward?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it’s unfair - it’s not illegal.

It’s unfair that Manchester United only pick really, really good football players rather than, say, me. It’s unfair that Microsoft cut special deals with the US government and not with my business. It’s unfair that people who pay for a first class ticket on an airline get better service than those who fly economy. It’s unfair that governments will give huge tax breaks to a company that wants to build a mine rather than to my company who wants to build a building.

The law does not protect you from unfairness or discrimination.

**Unless** ... that discrimination is on the basis of membership of a protected class, like race or gender or age. On the basis of which type of ticket you bought, no.